# const correctness of fftw3

Tags: c++, constants, well-formed

### Summary

What can I do if a function of an external library expect a non-const pointer (`double *`) but it is known that the values of it remains the same so according to const correctness I should pass a const pointer (`const double *`)?

### The situation

I'd like to create a function that calculates the auto-correlation of a vector but unfortunately it seems that [fftw3](http://www.fftw.org/doc/) (which is a C API) doesn't care about const correctness.
The function I'd like to call is:

```
fftw_plan fftw_plan_dft_r2c_1d(int n0,
                                    double *in, fftw_complex *out,
                                    unsigned flags);
```

And the code I'd like to create:

```
vector<double> autocorr(const vector<double>& data)
{
    vector<double> ret(data.size(), 0);
    // prepare other variables
    fftw_plan a = fftw_plan_dft_r2c_1d(size, &data.front(), tmp, FFTW_ESTIMATE);
    // do the rest of the work
    return ret;
}
```

Of course, this will not work because the argument of my function is `const vector<double>& data` so I can't call `&data.front()`. What is the most appropriate solution to keep the const-correctness of my code?

Comment: Quick and dirty solution: If you are sure that the data is not changed within the function, you can cast it to non const: instead of &data.front() use (const double *)&data.front().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're confronted with a C API that promises more than it shows with respect to `const`-correctness, it is time to `const_cast`:

```
vector<double> autocorr(const vector<double>& data)
{
    vector<double> ret(data.size(), 0);
    // prepare other variables
    fftw_plan a = fftw_plan_dft_r2c_1d(size, const_cast<double*>(&data.front()), tmp, FFTW_ESTIMATE);
    // do the rest of the work
    return ret;
}
```

Also note this sentence in the [documentation](http://www.fftw.org/doc/Real_002ddata-DFTs.html):

> in and out point to the input and output arrays of the transform, which may be the same (yielding an in-place transform). These arrays are overwritten during planning, unless FFTW_ESTIMATE is used in the flags.

Since you're using the `FFTW_ESTIMATE` flag, you should be fine in this case.

The reason FFTW developers decided not to duplicate this function for the sake of `const` is that in C, `const` isn't at all a big deal, and FFTW is a C library.

Comment: I'd not like to ruin the const correctness of my code by just using a small C code. Such small things can be very disturbing when a large code is maintained.

Answer (score 1):

First file a bug report against the library, then `const_cast` away the const-ness of `&data.front()`, for example `const_cast<double*>(&data.front())`

Comment: The problem is that some of the fftw "plans" act in-place. Thus, fftw would need different plan types and new API:s only usable with these types. Otherwise, a good point.